# Can we delete a UNIQUE and KEY index on id if we have a PRIMARY KEY?

Tags: mysql, indexing, primary-key

We are optimizing our company MySQL database. In many tables we find that there is:

- primary key on id
- unique key on id
- "key" on id

Since a PRIMARY key is already unique, I understand that the UNIQUE key is redundant and not needed. I also understand that KEY in this sense means nothing more than "index" and so it is also redundant.

[image]

1. Is it true that we could delete take the UNIQUE and KEY and have the same speed provided by the primary key index?
2. Could it be somehow that having these three indexes causes SELECT queries to be slower?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can drop the unique index and the key declaration. AFAIK, *every* SQL dbms implements a primary key constraint with a unique index. You can verify by running `explain`, dropping those two, and running `explain` again.

Redundant indexes *might* affect SELECT performance a little, because redundant indexes give the query planner more alternatives to consider. But I'd expect redundant indexes to have more effect on INSERT and DELETE statements, because those indexes have to be updated along with the table. (SQL UPDATE statements would require changes to the indexes only if the updated columns happen to be indexed.)